# Win10 Docker Build : Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I am going to create a docker image of angular web application to other windows machine. When it comes to the command execution :

```
docker build -t node .
```

It gives the following exception:

```
   Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:73
+ ... yContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing ht ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v8.11.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Would you please tell me how to correct the line 10 so that the zip file can be extracted ?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803 as installer

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.11.0
ENV NODE_SHA256 7b2409605c871a40d60c187bd24f6f6ddf10590df060b7d905ef46b3b3aa7f81

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v8.11.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1803

WORKDIR C:\nodejs
COPY --from=installer C:\nodejs\ .
RUN SETX PATH C:\nodejs
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

WORKDIR /app

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY src/WebSpa/package.json /app/src/WebSpa/package.json

WORKDIR /app/src/WebSpa
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

# add app
COPY . /app

# start app
CMD cd /app/src/WebSpa && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would help but I was having a similar issue using Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server and solved it by passing proxy server address as a parameter. Try:

Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-win-x64.zip" -Proxy http://yourproxyserver.com:port;

Comment: Could you please tell me if I have to install git and Java SE Development Kit  in one Dockerfile ? 

here is the question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296461/dockerfile-installing-multiple-msi

Comment: Hi, do you know about chocolatey.org? It may make your life a lot easier. I would give it a try. I am not sure if you can mix multiple FROM in one docker especially if they are using different Kernels. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to create a Dockerfile for my client machine to install the components